# How can you do phone-to-server development when simulators or Wi-Fi are not an option?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, wifi, simulator

I'm working on a project for multiple mobile phones (iPhone/BlackBerry/Android) in an organization where Wi-Fi is strictly forbidden. The nature of the project employs the phones' camera so simulator programs are not an option, and it needs to be able to communicate to a server, so some form of connectivity is required.

So the problem I have is that I can't use the camera of the phone as well as have it communicate with either my development machine or a QA cluster. I can't get the phone to be on a network wirelessly because of the aforementioned Wi-Fi ban. I can have it communicate over the Internet using 3G or whatever it uses to connect, but then it can't see my local machine or our QA environment because those aren't visible to the outside world. And I can't just use the simulator because I need to use the camera.

The way I see it my only real options are to simulate the communication to the server with "stunt" images loaded from files and then test the actual phone-to-server communication when the communication piece goes to production, or do as much testing as I can on some other Wi-Fi network, like the one at my house.

If these phones had Ethernet jacks - or could share the network connection of the machine they're attached to - my problem would be solved. Or if the simulators could use, say, a webcam attached via USB (which would not simulate the capabilities of the actual camera in the phone but might be better than nothing). The fact that different phone platforms have different simulators is unavoidable but complicates the situation further.

Has anyone ran into this issue before and has an inventive solution?

Comment: This is entirely different for iphone, blackberry, and android. In Android you can use adb to create a tunnel for network connectivity via usb. But it'll need to be rooted.

Comment: With iPhone thats similar, device has to be rooted too (jail broken) then it is OSX, you can tunnel trough ssh via USB.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to assign an IP address to a phone attached via USB.  This is a feature of the Motorola USB drivers for Android.  Other manufacturers may do the same.  When attached, they usually have an IP address of 192.168.16.x, which is given via DHCP from the host PC via the drivers.

At this point, you can attach ADB via TCP-IP mode and debug to it over ethernet with 'adb tcpip '.  You have to start out with the phone in USB mode for security reasons, but you can debug it in tcpip mode if necessary.  Not sure if IP packets that originate from the phone are routable to the outside internet via the PC connection, though.

Answer (score 1):

Check the rules around the wifi prohibition.  See if you can use an Airport Express wired to your development Mac inside a sealed Faraday cage room with no external network access.  Your organization may already have access to such rooms.

Or see if you can clone your QA servers (with non-confidential test data) at an outside test facility or test site.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to install a Wi-Fi access point, and a routing server if necessary, outside of the organization's network -- then tunnel the necessary ports and addresses through the organization's firewalls.

If the ban is so strict, or the firewall rules so unchangeable that even that is not feasible, I suggest a solution which is not inventive at all (comes straight from the books) but which I firmly believe will work better than any inventive one. Maybe not on this particular problem, but certainly for the future success of the project and the organization:

Buy some books on agile development, mark the chapters on impediments and dysfunctional organizations, and give them to your managers. Change your organization or change of organization.

Best.